# ROBLOX - how to pick two random players

Tags: lua, roblox

How do you make sure there's two people at least in the game before proceeding and how do you pick two random ones that are not the same?

I'm guessing something like

```
local players = game.Players:GetPlayers()
local status = game.ReplicatedStorage.Status

while true do
    for i = 10, 0, -1 do
        status.Value = "Starting in "..i
        wait(1)
    end
    
    local player1 = players[math.random(1,#players)]
    local player2 = players[math.random(1, #players)]
    
    print("Player 1 is "..tostring(player1))
    print("Player 2 is "..tostring(player2))
end
```

But not quite, because the two players can be accidentally the same, and I haven't done a check to make sure there's at least two players

Comment: Well, why don't you do just that? (1) check that there are at least two players; (2) repeat picking two random players until the two players aren't the same; alternatively, you could just remove one player from the list (say, swapping it to the end), then pick the other player from the remaining players - then they can't be the same player.

Answer (score 0):

```js
local Players=Game.Players

local function NEWGAME()

repeat players=Players:players()until#players>1 or not Players.PlayerAdded:Wait()
table.foreachi(players,function(i,v)getfenv()["player"..i]=table.remove(players,math.random(1,#players))end)

    for i = 10, 0, -1 do
        status.Text = "Starting in "..i
        wait(1)
    end
    print("Player 1 is "..tostring(player1))
    print("Player 2 is "..tostring(player2))

end;status=Instance.new("Hint",Workspace)NEWGAME()
```